# Is ROS compatible with Python and can it run on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking to add sensors to a robot using Raspberry Pi and the programming language Python. I was wondering if ROS would be a suitable operating system.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211528/is-ros-compatible-with-python-and-can-it-run-on-a-raspberry-pi/) by [Euan](https://answers.ros.org/users/22829/euan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS despite its name is not really an operating system, it is more like a middle-ware that facilitates controlling your robot and it works on top of Ubuntu or any other Linux distribution. I believe there is already builds of ROS that you can install directly on your Raspberry Pi, as if you were to install any other software on your board, you can find a tutorial [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi). And ROS is implemented in Python as well, if you do the ROS tutorials you will see that the rospy library offers access to all ROS functionalities from Python.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2015-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2